# How to find out what a python package does

Tags: python, module, package

EDIT I was being stupid. Just type help('package_name'.'pyb_name') which worked.

I would like to find out what is actually in a python package I have locally downloaded and installed with pip.

Typing help(package_name) just lists NAME, FILE (where the **init**.py is) and PACKAGE CONTENTS which is just one .pyd file.

I can't open the .pyd file to check what's inside(tbh not all that familiar with .pyds). These two with a 159byte **init**.pyc are the only files in the package.

I need to use this (not widely available) package for some university work.

Thanks.

Comment: What package is it?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the quick reply. Literally as I posted this I figured it out. I just typed 'from package_name import 'package.pyd''. I typed this multiple times which didn't work but I must have done something wrong somewhere because this time it worked. Which lead to me trying to delete the question, but you sneakily managed to get in there a couple of seconds before I tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't know what a python package does unless it is stated in its docs (on PyPI or in the repository) or without reading the code. A Python package can be anything that has a setup.py and either a single module or multiple files under a folder with a `__init__.py` file in it.

The fact that the `__init__.py` is empty doesn't mean anything other than the fact that its existence means there's a python package involved.

Any specific package you want to know about, you should look up for documentation or read the code to get a sense of its purpose.

Comment: Hi nir0s, the reason why I asked the question was because annoyingly there isn't any public documentation for it, and I couldn't read the code. But thanks for making it clear that the init doesn't need to be filled.

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: Not quiiite what I was looking for, so it doesn't answer the question I WANTED to ask, but I formulated my question vaguely so your answer does answer the question that I posted. :)